# Executing list of .sql files in certain order

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a directory having a number of .sql files.I am able to execute them.But, I want to execute them in certain order.So, for example if I have 4 files xy.sql,dy.sql,trim.sql and see.sql.I want to execute them in see.sql,dy.sql,trim.sql and xy.sql.What happens now is I get a list of files using DirectoryInfo object.Now, I need to sort them using my order.I am using C# 3.5

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to rename your files so that they sort into the correct order natively. This prevents having to maintain a separate "execution order" list somewhere.

Using a common prefix for the sql file names is a bit self-documenting as well, e.g.

```
exec1_see.sql
exec2_dy.sql
exec3_trim.sql and 
exec4_xy.sql
```

Comment: While possible, this approach can be fragile - it assumes that the people creating the files and the people running the utility understand there is a naming convention.

Comment: I would agree that there is always a chance of disaster if the people creating files and the people running the utility are not coordinated. In this case though, how does an extra document like an execution order list (especially hardcoded) reduce the risk ?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what the ordering algorithm is for your filenames. It doesn't appear to be entirely dictated by the filename (such as alphabetical ordering).

If you have arbitrary order in which you must execute these scripts, I would recommend that you create an additional file which defines that order, and use that to drive the ordering.

If the list of filenames is known at compile time, you could just hard-code that order in your code. I'm assuming, from your question, however, that the set of files is likely to change, and new ones may be added. If that's the case, I refer you to my previous paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a `List<string>` that consists of all your `.sql` files, and call the `List<T>.sort` function to sort it and then operate on the files based on the newly sorted sequence.

Answer (score 0):

number them and use a tool like my [SimpleScriptRunner](http://code.google.com/p/simplescriptrunner/) or the [Tarantino DB change tool](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/)